# Creating a docker image for windows that requires execution of setup executables

Tags: windows, docker, installation, dockerfile, docker-image

I am working on a docker image for windows. This image is based on the microsoft/nanoserver image. A few different components should be installed in the image so that containers made from it don't need to install these components any more. Well, I guess that's the purpose of every docker image.

However, my question is: how is that going to work for a Windows docker image and windows installers? Actually the setup executables for Windows have a GUI that require the user to interact with the installer and to provide different information. In case of Ubuntu it seems to be easier as I just run *apt-get install* and I can fetch the binaries and install them easily.

More specific I'm asking myself:

- I saw that some Windows setups have something like a *silent* or *quiet* switch. But I guess I can't assume that this is a Windows feature and every setup.exe has such this switch, right? That probably depends on if the creator of the setup included this option or not.
- How do I even start an installer on Windows using PowerShell? Is it just the command *setup.exe* or is it *Start-Process setup.exe* or ...?

Thanks in advance for your help & best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I guess I can't assume that this is a Windows feature and every setup.exe has such this switch, right?

No, but all packages I've encountered so far supports it one way or another.

> How do I even start an installer on Windows using PowerShell? Is it just the command setup.exe or is it Start-Process setup.exe

See this issue for details: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30395#issuecomment-274933963

I generally use `Start-Process -FilePath 'installer.exe' -ArgumentList 'arg1', 'arg2' -Wait`

Chocolatey may also be of use: https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/tree/master/chocolatey